# help me checking this Green-Ostrogradski theorem

Tags: vectors, physics, cylindrical-coordinates

Check the Green-Ostrogradski Theorem for the Vector Field
$A = 2Yi +3Xj – Z^2 k$
in the case of a cylinder of height $ℎ = 4$ and radius $ = 3$.